# Check for incomplete response

Tags: ios

When my application is launched, I am receiving an xml by hitting a service url and saving it in local db.I have applied reachability code to check if the connectivity is down.If its down ,then it will display an alert and won't proceed further as user interaction is disabled.However,there are times when internet connectivity goes to unreachable while getting the response.At this point the user interaction gets enabled as I get the response but with corrupted data which makes the application to crash when I want to use some data which is not there in xml.I am not able to follow a correct approach towards this.

Please help.

Comment: is there any kind of checksumming or way for you to validate that the response you've received is valid & useable?

Comment: it's xml... if it's truncated, then it won't be a valid xml document anymore. so parse/validate the xml before you do anything. if there's syntax errors, then it's bad and you shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate whatever input you receive. Even if you maintain network connectivity the whole time, there's always a chance that the service you use could send incomplete or incorrectly formatted data. Exactly how you do that is up to you, but two options are:

- Validate the data as you receive it from the service. When you receive your XML data, you probably parse it before storing it in your local database. That's a perfect opportunity to notice that the data is incomplete, and at that point you can decide how much (if any) of the data you're able to add to the database.
- Validate the data as you retrieve it from the database. In cases where data may trickle in in bits and pieces, you might prefer to do some sanity checks after you fetch the data to make sure that the database has given you everything you need before you proceed.

Comment: i am parsing about 55 tables in the xml.Now should i apply checks for each table name before i use them or just use the root tag for check?